# MySQL insert at end of table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with inserting a new item at the end of my MySQL table. When I insert the new item it appears after the last created item, but I want it to be entered at the bottom of the table. Suppose that I have a table id `= int,Primary Key` and `album=string` and the table is:

1. Wrath
2. Crack The Skye
3. Enter Shikari

What would the MySQL query be if PHP variable `$album=myAlbum` was to be inserted next, at the end of the table, and with the appropriate id?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to understand what a database is.

There is no "end" in the database. The rows take order only at the SELECT time.

So, you have to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your `SELECT` query to make rows in the desired order.

You may add another field to order your table by or use an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

You should define the id with [autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) so that MySQL will keep a counter that grows on each insert. That way you can order by id to know in which order stuff went in.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused - the order in the table does not matter. If you need a specific ordering, then query the data using an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `id` column to be `auto_increment`. This will give the behaviour you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

have your id autoincremented, and then in the insert query don't precise the id .

## with precising:

INSERT INTO `markers_greenZones`(`id`, `name`, `info`, `lat`, `lng`, `radius`, `markertype`, `time`) VALUES (1,'zone beta','this is info',-53.861034,100.171935,50000,'HighRisk','2017-25-2 10:15:12')

## witout precising:

INSERT INTO `markers_greenZones` (`name`, `info`, `lat`, `lng`, `radius`,`markertype`,`time`) VALUES ('zone alpha', 'you should be calm, stay together, respect each other, work together, and follow our instruction', 55.861034, 100.171936, 50000,'HighRisk','2017-25-2 10:15:12');

the incremental will be done automatically and your raw following the id (primary key) will be added to the end.