# How to add new row at the beginning of table instead of adding at the bottom?

Tags: php, html, laravel, phpmyadmin

I want to insert a new row to the top beginning of my table, but I don't know how?

```
@foreach ($dbData as $newField)
<form action="{{url('/update')}}" method="POST">  //update the form
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$newField->id}}">
<tr>
<td class="column"> {{$i}}</td>
<td class="column"> {{$newField->task}}</td>   //make new column
<td class="column"> {{$newField->description}}</td>
<td>
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status1" id={{$newField->id}} value="1" @if($newField->status == 1) checked @endif>
<label class="form-check-label" for={{$newField->id}}>
not started
</label>
</div>
<button type="submit">save</button>  //save form information to the table
```

Comment: Sort it before using it in foreach

Comment: Why do you want to do that. Use `sortBy()` instead.

Comment: `OrderBy('id','desc')` is what you need. it will fetch the latest data at the top. so you don't have to do any sorting at frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898477/mysql-insert-at-end-of-table) answer, there is no beginning or end (top or bottom) to a table.

And if you want to get the last inserted data first, you can use the SQL OrderBy functionality to achieve this.

Here is a good resource in w3schools
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp